# What is the reasoning for the self=self inside a class method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tostring

One popular python teacher wrote the following code (in a freely available youtube video related to str and repr methods)

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self,color,mileage):
        self.color = color
        self.mileage = mileage

    def __str__(self):
        return 'a {self.color} car'.format(self=self)

>>>my_car = Car('red', 37281)
>>>print(my_car)
a red car
```

The body of the `__str__` looked very interesting. 
While I do understand what the 2 self's are and how the statement evaluates, I didnt understand the reason for using such a definition.

I tried a simpler alternative definition for the method:

```py
    def __str__(self):
        return "this is a {x} car".format(x=self.color)
```

and it seemed to work just fine.

```py
>>> car1 = Car("grey", "ritz")
>>> str(car1)
'this is a grey car'
```

But am sure there is a valid reason for the suggestion:

```py
def __str__(self):
        return 'a {self.color} car'.format(self=self)
```

which am not getting.
Can anyone explain this to me ?

Does the definition have any impact based on whether `Car` class gets subclassed later and if this `Car.__str__()` gets called via a `super` call ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to include values in a string is to pass key/value pairs to the `format` method; the value assigned to the string is then available with a `{}` placeholder by the name of the key. The code shown could replace the *key* with any name other than `self`:

```
    return 'a {x.color} car'.format(x=self)
```

One rationale for f-strings was to decrease the amount of repetition needed.

```
return f'a {self.color} car'
```

Here, `{self.color}` is simply an expression using the name currently in scope, without having to pass introduce a new name via the `format` method.

(Even before f-strings, some would write something like `'a {self.color} car'.format(**locals())`, which would include `self` in the names available to the format string. This could be undesirable, though, if it also included a lot of *additional* unnecessary variables, aside from hurting readability and providing room for hard-to-track bugs due to other scoping issues.)

Comment: For completeness: The mentioned [f-string are available since Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)

Comment: Does the definition in question, have any advantage based on whether `Car` class gets subclassed later and if this `Car.__str__()` gets called via a `super` call ? Or it makes no difference ?

Comment: No, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You passing a `self` (variable) object as `self` (variable name) object to be formatted. It's same as, for example - replace `self` with `yo`. Code a bit ambiguous.

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'a {yo.color} car'.format(yo=self)
```

I guess we can ask Dan about this directly
https://stackoverflow.com/users/767412/dbader

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative version and the one you are asking about are exactly equivalent, except for naming. `self` is not a reserved word in Python, so this is just a variable name. The author of this code must have thought this name would make the role of the variable clearer, but it seems to have had the opposite effect.